# Default and hover states for bounty award buttons don’t match on Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, design, meta

This is what the default state of the “bounty award” button looks like on Meta Stack Exchange:

[image: Screenshot of button default state]

Notice how it doesn’t match the general style of the site. The hover state, on the other hand, does:

[image: Screenshot of button hover state]

Because they’re of different sizes, moving the cursor over the button shifts the whole post over; it’s a bit annoying.

[image: Overlaid screenshots]